# htmlunit : checkbox not getting checked

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit for setting a checkbox in a page. Html code for checkbox is :

```
<input id="Checkbox" type="checkbox"  name="Checkbox" style="color:Black;"/>
```

My java code to set checkbox is :

```
HtmlCheckBoxInput checkBox = page.getHtmlElementById("Checkbox");
checkBox.setChecked(true);
        
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("src/test/page-dumps/page-3.html"),page.asXml(),"UTF-8");
```

When I open `page-3.html` in my browse, ckeckbox is unchecked. Why is it not checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is not checked because real browsers don't add an attribute.

Test the below with real browser:

```html
<html><head>
<script>
  function test() {
    var e = document.getElementById('myid');
    e.checked = true;
    alert(e.outerHTML);
  }
</script>
</head><body onload="test()">
  <input type=checkbox id=myid>
</body></html>
```

There is an alert of

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myid">
```

without any `checked` attribute.

You should instead use:

```
checkBox.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the `checked` attribute to the `<input>` element?